# Is old brewed coffee too unsafe to drink?

Tags: food-safety, coffee

So, yesterday i accidentally left a cup of Dunkin Donuts Coffee (with cream and maybe milk) on my bathroom windowsill while i went to work for at least 8 hours, then refrigerated it when i got home. It's in the fridge at work as we speak. Is it still ok to drink?

Comment: Even if it's not unsafe, it's going to taste awful...ler. Are you that desperate to save yourself $1?

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer, because it's based entirely my own gut reaction, but you should dump it.  Better safe than sorry, and you will be sorry if you drink that.

Comment: With dairy in it I would get rid of it. If there was no dairy, it would   ok, but will not taste good at all

Answer (score 2):

According to NRAEF food safety standards, it should be thrown out.

Anything that can potentially grow bacteria should be thrown out if it has been left in what's called the Temperature Danger Zone (40-140F) for more than 6 hours. The dairy added to the coffee in question was an ideal culture for bacterial development at room temperature.

All things considered, I wouldn't drink it, and neither should you. Pour it out- it's only a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how long it's been out. I've seen mold form the second day to "plain" unflavored coffee (no milk, no sugar).

I've kept refrigerated brewed flavored coffee in an air-tight container for a week or more without problems. (I add a bit to unflavored hot coffee so the flavor isn't overwhelming).